# Encrypting a symmetric key or Small File using TPM and Windows (TBS?)

Tags: encryption, rsa, trusted-computing

I'm looking at encrypting a small (500bytes) file using the TPM. This is either doing assymetric encryption with the TPM directly, or using the TPM to store a symmetric key for decryption. This needs to work on Windows (7).

I'm assuming I can do this with tbsip_Submit_Command through The TBS/WIn32_TBS, but haven't really seen any concrete info on how to prepare that sort of statement.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this fairly easily with jtSS http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/index.php?item=jtss/readme

After installing the windows service,
jtt create_key to create a key, then jtt seal to perform the sealing.

example commands:

```
>jtt create_key -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -t storage
>jtt seal -i message.txt -o message.enc -p 1,2,5 -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>jtt unseal -i message.enc -o out.txt -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

-p specifies the PCR registers, and these represent the different values of the machine state (bios, boot devices, etc)
-u is the UUID of the key being used.